# An application for Scheduling Coping of files/Folders in Linux/Java

Tags: java, linux, copy, scheduling

I Simply searching for a simple application in Linux/Java that i can schedule copying of files/folders at specified Hour of night....

Comment: [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/).

Comment: cron and rsync or scp makes this a online line of configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set it up as a scheduled cron job.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab

The scheduled job can then run a simple shell script with the copy/etc commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cronjob
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5

This would run 5 minutes after midnight every day
crontab -e

5 0 * * *       cp /dir/* tmp/dir/